# How to convert RowMatrix to local Matrix?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, matrix, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I have a problem regarding matrices in Spark.

Suppose I have a `RowMatrix` named X like this:

```
0.5    0.5  
0.25   0.0625
0.125  0.125
0.0625 0.0625
0.0625 0.25
```

Now what I want to do is to multiply this `RowMatrix` with the transposed version of the `RowMatrix` X.

```
0.5 0.25   0.125 0.0625 0.0625
0.5 0.0625 0.125 0.0625 0.25
```

Now, for all I know I can't multiply a `RowMatrix` with another `RowMatrix`, it have to be a `RowMatrix` and a local matrix. Hence, I tried to convert the `RowMatrix` to a local dense matrix using this code:

```
val arr = X.rows.map(x=>x.toArray).collect.flatten
val Xlocal = Matrices.dense(X.numRows.toInt,X.numCols.toInt,arr)
```

But it doesn't convert it properly because `RowMatrix` was row-based I think? I'm not really sure and the local dense matrix was stored in column-major order, so the order is messed up.

Can someone help me how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`RowMatrix`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-data-types.html#rowmatrix) do not have any row indices and should only be used when the row order does not matter. If the order does matter use an [`IndexedRowMatrix`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-data-types.html#indexedrowmatrix) instead.

It is possible to convert a `RowMatrix` to an `IndexedRowMatrix` but note that the **order is not guaranteed** and it's preferable to use `IndexedRowMatrix` directly. Assuming `rowMat` is the matrix to convert:

```
val indRowMax = new IndexedRowMatrix(rowMat.rows.zipWithIndex().map{ case (v, id) => IndexedRow(id, v)})
```

An `IndexedRowMatrix` can easily be converted to a local matrix:

```
val localMat = indRowMax.toBlockMatrix().toLocalMatrix()
```

and to multiply with the transpose can be done as follows:

```
indRowMax.multiply(localMat.transpose)
```

Comment: thanks for the help, i decided to use indexedRowMatrix instead